# How to change active Bottom bar tab background color

Tags: android

I am using roughike/BottomBar below link shown to a image so how am i make look like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wybr2.png please help

Comment: what is this???

Comment: please read again migea

Comment: @user3597818 Use this activeColor="#FF0000"

Comment: @sallu only change icon and text color not overall bg select tab

Comment: @user3597818 but in image it is changing whole tab color..what exactly you want?

Comment: @sallu i want to same when my tab is select whole tab color look like this

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your `styles.xml` :

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

or programmatically

```
window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)
```

Of course you should bear in mind that this will only work with API>21.

Also refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int)).

Comment: i am not using material design navigationbar i am using bottom bar using this link

Answer (score 0):

Define a selector drawable and also make two drawable for selected and unselected tab 
selector tab tab_background.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background_unselected" android:state_selected="false" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

tab_background_selected.xml in drawable folder

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#d13fdd1a" />
</shape>
```

tab_background_unselected.xml in drawable folder

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#3F51B5" />
</shape>
```

And after all that in your style.xml mention your selector to use

```
 <style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_background</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#ff00ff</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: please read agin my question i am using Bottom bar not for Tablayout.  refer this link  
github.com/roughike/BottomBar